# Get more than one rows item for one iteration in ADF-Mobile

Tags: listview, iterator, oracle-adf-mobile

I want to know how to get two row attributes in one iteration in ADF Mobile.

For my requirement, I need to display the image in the page as below:

```
image1     image2

image3     image4

image5     ...
```

So I use the listView to do this.

```
<amx:listView var="row" value="#{ImageList.collectionModel}"
              fetchSize="-1" id="lv1" rendered="true">
    <amx:listItem id="li1">
        <amx:tableLayout width="100%" id="tl3">
            <amx:rowLayout id="rl2">
                <amx:cellFormat width="100%" halign="center" id="cf4">
                    <amx:image source="#{row.imageFile}" id="i2"/>
                </amx:cellFormat>
                <amx:cellFormat width="100%" halign="center" id="cf5">
                    <amx:image source="#{row.imageFile}" id="i3"/>
                </amx:cellFormat>
            </amx:rowLayout>
        </amx:tableLayout>
    </amx:listItem>
</amx:listView>
```

See, Here I am able to receive the same row  in each iteration. How can I get 2 different row in each iteration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about UI, no need to put two images in one iterator, read more about oracle maf UI and you will figure it out with some css [Creating the MAF AMX User Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/mobile200/mobile/develop-oepe/oepe-maf-ui-components.htm).

**For Example Try:**

> Width:50px;float:left; display:relative;

On `listitem inline style property` on the simplist list view in oracle MAF.